# Create another model upon user new registration in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm using [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) to do the new user registration. Right after a new user is created, I would also like to create a profile for that user.

My `create` method in the `registrations_controller.rb` is as follows:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    def create
      super
      session[:omniauth] = nil unless @user.new_record?

      # Every new user creates a default Profile automatically
      @profile = Profile.create
      @user.default_card = @profile.id
      @user.save

    end
```

But, it is not creating a new Profile and neither is the field for @user.default_card is being filled in. How can I create a new Profile automatically upon each new user registration with devise?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would put this functionality into an `before_create` callback function on the user model since it is essentially model logic, would only not add another save call and is just generally more elegant.

One possible reason why your code is not working is that `@profile = Profile.create` is not executed successfully because it is failing validations or something. This would result in `@profile.id` being `nil` and thus `@user.default_card` is `nil`.

Here is how I would implement this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  ...

  before_create :create_profile

  def create_profile
    profile = Profile.create
    self.default_card = profile.id
    # Maybe check if profile gets created and raise an error 
    #  or provide some kind of error handling
  end
end
```

In your code(or mine), you can always put a simple `puts` to check if the new profile is getting created. i.e. `puts (@profile = Profile.create)`

Comment: Thanks! You are right that I had validations on the Profile model which didn't allow me to create the profile. Many thanks! So now I can automatically created the new profile with every new user registration. Any idea how I can evoke the validations when the profile is edited the next time after creation?

Comment: ok figured out that in validations you can only validate upon certain actions. Case solved Thanks :) http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#on

Answer (score 0):

Another method in the similar lines is this ( use the build_profile method )  :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :async,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: [:facebook]


  has_one :profile

  before_create :build_default_profile

  private
  def build_default_profile
    # build default profile instance. Will use default params.
    # The foreign key to the owning User model is set automatically
    build_profile
    true # Always return true in callbacks as the normal 'continue' state
    # Assumes that the default_profile can **always** be created.
    # or
    # Check the validation of the profile. If it is not valid, then
    # return false from the callback. Best to use a before_validation
    # if doing this. View code should check the errors of the child.
    # Or add the child's errors to the User model's error array of the :base
    # error item
  end
end
```