# Rails 4 - setup, automatically create profile when new user created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path, routes, resources

I have tried to tidy this post up so it doesnt seem so long for new comers. It includes errors resulting from following suggestions from others in the answers below.

I am trying to make an app with Rails 4.

I use devise and omniauth.

I have models for user and profile. User has one profile and profile belongs to user.

My aim is to use the user model for all the things that the user doesn't really touch. I use the profile model for things the user does maintain.

When a new user is created, I want the user to be redirected to their profile page, which should be partly populated with details created in the user model.

I'm having trouble.

I have:

User.rb

```
has_one :profile
```

Profile.rb

```
belongs_to :user
```

Omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb

```
if @user.persisted?
  sign_in_and_redirect_user(:user, authentication.user.profile)
  set_flash_message(:notice, :success, kind: "#{provider}".capitalize) if is_navigational_format?
else
  session["devise.#{provider}_data"] = env["omniauth.auth"]
  redirect_to new_user_registration_url
end
```

I have also tried in the call back redirect:

```
 sign_in_and_redirect @user,  event: :authentication
```

profiles/show.html.erb

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs 8 col-xs-offset-1">
            <%= @profile.user.formal_name %>


            <%= @profile.occupation %>
            <%= @profile.qualification.awards %>
            <%= @profile.overview %>
            <%= @profile.research_interests %>

        </div>

        <div class="col-xs 3">
            <div class="geobox">
            <%= render 'addresses/location' %>
            <%= @profile.working_languages %>
            <%= @profile.external_profile %>

            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs 10 col-xs-offset-1">
            <%= render 'profiles/activity' %>
        </div>
    </div>  

</div>
```

_nav.html.erb

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
                    Hi <%= link_to(current_user.first_name.titlecase, profile_path(current_user)) %></span>
```

I have also tried:

_nav.html.erb

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
                    Hi <%= link_to(current_user.first_name.titlecase, user_profile_path(current_user.profile)) %></span>
```

What do I need to do to add some kind of functionality to let a new user go to their profile page?

Currently, when I try logging in and clicking on the nav bar link, I want to go to the profile page. Instead, I go to an error message which says the page I am looking for does not exist. The path it is looking for starts at profile (rather than user/profile) -not sure if that's a clue.

My routes are:

Profiles:

```
profiles GET       /profiles(.:format)                    profiles#index
                         POST      /profiles(.:format)                    profiles#create
             new_profile GET       /profiles/new(.:format)                profiles#new
            edit_profile GET       /profiles/:id/edit(.:format)           profiles#edit
                 profile GET       /profiles/:id(.:format)                profiles#show
                         PATCH     /profiles/:id(.:format)                profiles#update
                         PUT       /profiles/:id(.:format)                profiles#update
                         DELETE    /profiles/:id(.:format)                profiles#destroy
```

User:

```
user_password POST      /users/password(.:format)              devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET       /users/password/new(.:format)          devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET       /users/password/edit(.:format)         devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH     /users/password(.:format)              devise/passwords#update
                         PUT       /users/password(.:format)              devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET       /users/cancel(.:format)                users/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST      /users(.:format)                       users/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET       /users/sign_up(.:format)               users/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET       /users/edit(.:format)                  users/registrations#edit
                         PATCH     /users(.:format)                       users/registrations#update
                         PUT       /users(.:format)                       users/registrations#update
                         DELETE    /users(.:format)                       users/registrations#destroy
       user_confirmation POST      /users/confirmation(.:format)          devise/confirmations#create
   new_user_confirmation GET       /users/confirmation/new(.:format)      devise/confirmations#new
                         GET       /users/confirmation(.:format)          devise/confirmations#show
             user_unlock POST      /users/unlock(.:format)                devise/unlocks#create
         new_user_unlock GET       /users/unlock/new(.:format)            devise/unlocks#new
                         GET       /users/unlock(.:format)                devise/unlocks#show
           finish_signup GET|PATCH /users/:id/finish_signup(.:format)     users#finish_signup
```

NEW ATTEMPT:
Further to the suggestion below, I nested the resources as:

```
  resources :users do
     resources :profile
  end
```

and I changed the redirect to:

```
def self.provides_callback_for(provider)
    class_eval %Q{
      def #{provider}
        @user = User.find_for_oauth(env["omniauth.auth"])

        if @user.persisted?
           sign_in_and_redirect [current_user, current_user.profile || current_user.build_profile]

          set_flash_message(:notice, :success, kind: "#{provider}".capitalize) if is_navigational_format?
        else
          session["devise.#{provider}_data"] = env["omniauth.auth"]
          redirect_to new_user_registration_url
        end
      end
    }
  end
```

I get this error: NoMethodError (undefined method `profile' for nil:NilClass):

NEXT ATTEMPT:

I keep all of the above, but try replacing the redirect like so:

```
def self.provides_callback_for(provider)
    class_eval %Q{
      def #{provider}
        @user = User.find_for_oauth(env["omniauth.auth"])

        if @user.persisted?
           sign_in_and_redirect [@user, @user.profile || @user.build_profile]

          set_flash_message(:notice, :success, kind: "#{provider}".capitalize) if is_navigational_format?
        else
          session["devise.#{provider}_data"] = env["omniauth.auth"]
          redirect_to new_user_registration_url
        end
      end
    }
  end

RuntimeError (Could not find a valid mapping for [#<User id: 1 ...
```

and then it lists all the attributes in the user table, and then shows:

```
#<Profile id: nil, user_id: 1,
```

followed by all the attributes in the profiles table.

A NEW ATTEMPT

I found this post: [Rails Trying to create a profile after the user has been created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30541779/rails-trying-to-create-a-profile-after-the-user-has-been-created)

And I tried adding:

```
 after_create do
    create_user_profile
  end
```

to my user model.

I kept the redirect the same as I had it (following Alexei's suggestion) and tried again.

I get the same error message:

```
RuntimeError (Could not find a valid mapping for [#<User id: 1
```

Can anyone see how to solve this?

A FURTHER ATTEMPT:

I then found this post:
    [Ruby on Rails - Creating a profile when user is created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19292645/ruby-on-rails-creating-a-profile-when-user-is-created)

which says for Rails 4 (which I use), I need this callback only:

after_create :create_profile

When I try this, I get the same error as above.

AN IDEA:

I used scaffolding generator for my profile controller.

My create method is:

```
  def create
    @profile = Profile.new(profile_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @profile.save
        format.html { redirect_to @profile }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @profile }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @profile.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Is this error maybe something to do with the user id not being specifically referenced in this method. I have whitelisted user_id in the strong params for the profiles controller.

A NEW ATTEMPT

This article suggests using build_profile instead of create_profile.

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8337682/create-another-model-upon-user-new-registration-in-devise
```

I changed my user.rb to

```
  after_create :build_profile
```

When I save this and try I get the same error.

ANOTHER ATTEMPT

Matt's answer in this post suggests that I have to include a definition of build_profile as:

```
 after_create :build_profile

  def build_profile
    Profile.create(user: self) # Associations must be defined correctly for this syntax, avoids using ID's directly.
  end
```

I changed my user.rb to:

```
  after_create :build_profile

  def build_profile
    Profile.create(user: self) # Associations must be defined correctly for this syntax, avoids using ID's directly.
  end
```

When I save and try this, I get a similar error, but with more information. The logs still show:

```
RuntimeError (Could not find a valid mapping for [#<User id: 1,
```

But after all of that error message, it gives this new piece of information:

```
SQL (2.9ms)  INSERT INTO "profiles" ("user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["user_id", 1], ["created_at", "2015-12-18 21:58:49.993866"], ["updated_at", "2015-12-18 21:58:49.993866"]]
2015-12-18T21:58:49.966648+00:00 app[web.1]:   Profile Load (1.5ms)  SELECT  "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE "profiles"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 1]]
2015-12-18T21:58:50.007428+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 113ms (ActiveRecord: 21.8ms)
2015-12-18T21:58:49.941385+00:00 app[web.1]:   User Load (1.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
```

Does this offer any light on the problem?

UPDATE

I tried this again (without making any changes to the code). Now I get an error, but this time the logs say:

```
RuntimeError (Could not find a valid mapping for [#<User id: 1, first_name: "Me", last_name: "Ma", email: "mema@gmail.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$jqQn..HSvlcNtfAH/28.DQoWetO...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 16, current_sign_in_at: "2015-12-15 09:57:14", last_sign_in_at: "2015-12-15 09:27:07", current_sign_in_ip: #<IPAddr: IPv4:49.191.55>, last_sign_in_ip: #<IPAddr: IPv4:49.191.135.255.255>, confirmation_token: nil, confirmed_at: "2015-12-15 09:02:58", confirmation_sent_at: "2015-12-15 08:42:48", unconfirmed_email: nil, failed_attempts: 0, unlock_token: nil, locked_at: nil, created_at: "2015-12-09 23:53:20", updated_at: "2015-12-15 09:57:14", image: nil>, #<Profile id: 1, user_id: 1, title: nil, hero_image: nil, overview: nil, occupation: nil, external_profile: nil, working_languages: nil, created_at: "2015-12-18 21:58:49", updated_at: "2015-12-18 21:58:49">]):
```

The difference this time is that the profile has a user id key of 1. Previously, this was nil.

Comment: How is you `rake routes` looking for user and profile paths? :)

Comment: Hi David, I copied them above

Comment: "The path it is looking for starts at profile (rather than user/profile) -not sure if that's a clue."

Would you rather have each user link to a unique profile? 
Or do you want to be able to visit `domain/profile/1` to get first profile?

Comment: Each user should have their  own profile page. I'm trying to make it so when each user logs in, they are redirected to their own profile page

Comment: Do you have an `after_sign_in_path_for` in your applications controller?
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in

Comment: I just have this in my callbacks controller:            sign_in_and_redirect @user,  event: :authentication

Comment: Why the array in `sign_in_and_redirect`?

Comment: it's Alexei's suggestion below

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested resources

```
resources :users do
  resource :profile
end
```

and then

```
redirect_to [current_user, current_user.profile || current_user.build_profile]
```

Comment: Hi - I tried this, but get this error: NoMethodError (undefined method `profile' for nil:NilClass):
2015-12-15T10:33:09.278064+00:00 app[web.1]:

Comment: It tells you do not have current_user (current_user == nil). Use @user if it is defined.

Comment: Hi Alexei. I use devise. I have the current_user helper available. Also, are you sure it's talking about user, when the method says profile? Thanks very much for the help

Comment: I still get the same error when I try it with @user. I updated the post to show above.

Comment: The error clearly indicates you are sending message 'profile' to NilClass (i.e. nil.profile). To double check, add 'puts current_user.inspect' right before 'redirect_to'.

Comment: Hi Alexi, I tried your suggestion. I get the same error as I set out above. When I inspect the heroku logs after trying the line you suggested above, I don't see anything different to the error I get without that line.

Answer (score 0):

You've added `sing_in_and_redirect_user` in your callbacks controller.
To edit the path it redirects to you should also override and edit the
`after_sign_in_path_for` in your `applications_controller`.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    request.env['omniauth.origin'] || stored_location_for(resource) || root_path
  end
end
```

Here you can edit the actual path is redirects to. Not sure about the omniauth part, but you could add `profile_path(resource.profile)`.

Reference:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in